# php-PDF file not generating(using FPDF)

Tags: php, pdf, localhost, fpdf

I am running a simple example like this :

```
<?php require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
 $pdf = new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
 $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
 $pdf->Output();
 ?>
```

the output which was expected as like a pdf page with a text of Hello World Written in it...but I got no pdf ..there is no error generation neither in the page nor in the console.the page came blank that's not pdf file..So how to fix this..?

Comment: Not able to reproduce problem. PDF is generated and displayed correctly to me in the browser. Have you copied fonts folder into fpdf.php script's location ? Also check fonts file permissions. Have you set `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in your test php script ? (otherwise you will not see any PHP error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add file name;

```
$pdf->Output("myPdfFile.pdf", "F");
```

Comment: filename can be anything random?

Comment: I tried it right now ..but as usual nothing happened

Comment: i edit my last comment. try it, any error? i worked now this sample.

Comment: because only created pdf files. if you go to your php files directory,  you will see pdf files. what do you want after created pdf file php? redirect, open pdf file etc...

Comment: Right,,there are pdf files created in that directory but it is not showing in the browser..why?

Comment: if you want show it on browser, you shoud write pdf file name into web browser url. example: http://localhost:8000/myPdfFile.pdf

Comment: it worked but is there any process to show that pdf on the webpage avoiding the process of manually modifying the url bar of the browser?

Comment: hım, you can do it.  `header("Location: http://localhost:8000/myPdfFile.php");
die();`

Comment: Now I want them to have unique ids so that it can be generated uniquely

Comment: okay, $filename = uniqid() . '.pdf'; $pdf->Output($filename, "F"); header("Location: http://localhost:8000" . $filename); die();